# Vyatta configuration in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking for softlayer api to get a configuration of gateway. 
As far as i know, Standalone means "Not HA". Is there any flag to know a configuration of Gateway ?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways?objectMask=mask[memberCount]

Method: Get
```

> - memberCount = 1   means "Standalone"
> - memberCount > 1   means "High Availability"

References:

- [SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkGateways](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways)